# How to write to an EEPROM during Linux kernel reboot?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, device-tree

I need to store a flag in an EEPROM based on the `arg` in `int reboot(int magic, int magic2, int cmd, void *arg);`. The eeprom is defined in my device tree like this:

```
eeprom2: eeprom@51 {
    compatible = "atmel,24c02";
    reg = <0x51>;
    pagesize = <16>;
};
```

I can also read/write the eeprom via a sysfs file in userspace. That userspace write ultimately calls `at24.c:at24_write(struct at24_data *at24, const char *buf, loff_t off, size_t count)`. From my machine's restart() method under arch/arm, how can I get the pointer to the correct at24_data structure so I can call at24_write()?

Comment: @NickT : I know it doesn't look android related, but this is how Android communicates to the bootloader on reboot that it should restart into recovery mode. The saving of a flag piece. The EEPROM implementation is machine-specific.

Comment: I think this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7636801/which-is-the-cleaner-way-to-get-a-pointer-to-a-struct-device-in-linux) might be the solution.

Comment: Using u-Boot to do this kind of thing could be a solution.

Comment: @LPs: Heh. I'm writing to the eeprom from the kernel so U-Boot can read it after the CPU has been reset.

Comment: I misunderstood. I though that you need to store data before kernel boot.